# Get max value per id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query :

```
BEGIN 
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tblquota`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblquota (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) AS
     SELECT c.id as user_id
         , c.`email`
         , h.`packageid` as pack_id
         , p.`name` as pack_name
         , max(CASE 
             WHEN `name` = "Basic" THEN '100'
             WHEN `name` = "Silver" THEN '100'
             WHEN `name` = "Gold" THEN '100'
                 ELSE '10'
            END) as quota
     FROM `tblclients` c
     LEFT JOIN `tblhosting` h ON c.id = h.userid 
     INNER JOIN `tblproducts` p ON h.packageid = p.id 
     ORDER BY c.id;
END
```

In this case, the query will only get the max value for only one customer. I would like to get the value per customer.

table **clients**:

```
id | email          | status
----------------------------
1  | user1@mail.com | Active
2  | user2@mail.com | Inactive
3  | user3@mail.com | Active
```

table **tblhosting**

```
id | userid | packageid | domainstatus 
------------------------------------------------
1  | 1      | 3         | Active
2  | 1      | 2         | Active
3  | 2      | 1         | Active
4  | 2      | 2         | Active
5  | 2      | 3         | Inactive
6  | 3      | 1         | Active
```

table **tblproducts**

```
id | name 
-----------
1  | Basic
2  | Silver
3  | Gold
```

I expect result like :

```
id | user_id | email          | pack_id | pack_name | quota
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | user1@mail.com | 3       | Gold      | 1000
2  | 2       | user2@mail.com | 2       | Silver    | 100
3  | 3       | user3@mail.com | 1       | Basic     | 10
```

Comment: You need `GROUP BY c.id`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `Max OVER (PARTITION BY user_id)`

Comment: Can you show how to use it ?

Comment: Max(case when..…..) over (partition by user_id) as quota